# How to Implement main/fallback function pattern in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, fallback

I want to create function which will try to call main function. If it is ok return the resutl of this function outside. But if it is failed - call another function(fallback function) and return its result outside. If both failed - exception of second function should be propagated.

I've creare dollowing function:

```
  fun<T> callWithFallback(
        main: () -> T,
        fallback: () -> T
    ): T = try {
        main()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        logger.warn(e) { "main call failed: ${e.message}" }
        if (/*some condition*/) {
            try {
                fallback()
            } catch (e: LDAPException) {
                logger.warn(e) { "Repeated call failed: ${e.message}" }
                throw e
            }
        }
        throw e
    }
```

in case of main is failed - `fallback()` is called but even if it is successsful - exception is thrown (last `throw e` is called)

I tried to add `return`

```
  fun<T> callWithFallback(
        main: () -> T,
        fallback: () -> T
    ): T = try {
        main()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        logger.warn(e) { "main call failed: ${e.message}" }
        if (/*some condition*/) {
            try {
                return fallback()
            } catch (e: LDAPException) {
                logger.warn(e) { "Repeated call failed: ${e.message}" }
                throw e
            }
        }
        throw e
    }
```

But it leads to compile error.

How can I fix it ?

Comment: What is `/*some condition*/`? What should happen if `main` throws an exception, and `/*some condition*/` is false? Did you perhaps want to put `throw e` in an `else`? `if (/*some condition*/) { ... } else { throw e }`?

Comment: @Sweeper let's say that it is based on exception type.

If condition is false - fallback should not be called and exception should be thrown. Yes, else is also good  but it is not an issue I think

Comment: @Sweeper is right. The problem comes from the if that does not have any else. An if without else is a **statement**. Here, you want an **expression**, because you need to return a value from within the if. So, the else is required. To convince you: just put your throw in a else. You'll see, it will work then. Also, if you remove the `throw e` after the if, then Kotlin compilation fail with the following explanation: `
'if' must have both main and 'else' branches if used as an expression`

Comment: Also, to know what value to return, Kotlin use the **last** statement/expression from the block. Currently, the last expression in the `catch` is `throw e`. By moving it in else, the last expression in the catch is the if/else. (and to know what to return from the if/else, Kotlin looks at the last expression inside it, etc.)

Comment: @aminin, you should write your two comments as an answer. It explains it perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of your current implementation comes from the `if` statement without `else` in your first `catch` clause :

1. To know what to return from the catch, Kotlin compiler looks at the **last statement it contains**. Here, it is `throw e`, not the if that contains the wanted fallback.
2. As your `if` has no `else` branch, it is considered **a statement instead of an expression**. Therefore, it cannot return anything. You can test this assertion by removing `throw e` from the `catch` clause. The compiler will then issue a warning to explain it cannot return anything from the `catch` clause:

   > 'if' must have both main and 'else' branches if used as an expression

To fix your problem, you can move the `throw e` statement at the bottom of your function in an else clause, like so:

```kotlin
  fun<T> callWithFallback(
        main: () -> T,
        fallback: () -> T
    ): T = try {
        main()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        logger.warn(e) { "main call failed: ${e.message}" }
        if (/*some condition*/) {
            try {
                fallback()
            } catch (e: LDAPException) {
                logger.warn(e) { "Repeated call failed: ${e.message}" }
                throw e
            }
        } else {
            throw e
        }
    }
```

Doing so makes the `if/else` the latest statement in the `catch` clause, and as it is an expression (due to the presence of the else branch), its result is considered the return value of the catch.

Comment: Thank you but `return fallback()` must be replaces with `fallback()`